# how to create a service in docker registry without pulling?

Tags: docker-swarm

I want create an image like Busybox with docker in the first server and I want to create its service in the second server.

After this command :

```
docker service create --constraint "node.hotname == <second server>"
--endpoint-mode dnsrr --log-driver json-file --log-opt max-size=32m --log-opt max-file=16 --name test-pull --network cluster-network2 --replicas 1 --restart-condition any registry.cheshmak.me/cheshmak/busybox:v1
```

I should pull it again in the second server, I don't want to do this for second time.

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Create a local registry push images to your local registry and use that registry to as an endpoint to pull images.